# Labelling point features with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, labeling, annotation

I have an attribute table with some fields and I want to display on map the values of a field of this table. Table is a shapefile. I need to turn on label of a field automatically with arcpy, so I tried to use contour annotation but it gives error.

```
Field= "Teste"
env.workspace = "F:/ArcGIS/Trab/Model/Subestações.shp"
arcpy.ContourAnnotation_cartography('Subestações', env.workspace, Field , 50000, "ContourTeste", "BLACK", 
"", "PAGE", "")

ERROR 000366: Invalid geometry type
```

I could to use this function for a polyline feature, and with this error I think that problem is this function can't be used with point feature.

How I can turn on label of a field with arcpy?

Comment: When asking about errors from ArcPy can you always provide the code snippet that produced any error messages that you present, please?  Turning on labels is probably the `showLabels` property of a Layer object.

Comment: I already I edited my answer @PolyGeo

Comment: A shapefile has no label; only a layer does. You will need to address either a layer file or a layer in a map. See [this similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24313/how-to-turn-on-labels-of-a-layer-file-with-arcpy).

Comment: When I tried to run your code snippet using one of my shapefiles it gave an error: `NameError: name 'env' is not defined`  In this case I could make an assumption about what one of the earlier lines in your script may have been but I think this illustrates that you have not provided us with a tested code snippet that we can just copy/paste and then run against our own test data.  If you left out that line I always wonder what other lines that may be critical to your problem have also been left out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display labels in a shapefile from a specific field in your attribute table. Use this function.

First you need to use the `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` tool to turn your shapefile into a layer so it can be brought into arc

```
 def labell(wah, field):
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        if lyr.name == wah:
            if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
                for lblClass in lyr.labelClasses:
                    lblClass.expression = '"{}" + {} +  "{}"'.format("<CLR red='255' green='255' blue='255'><FNT size = '8'>", field, "</FNT></CLR>")
                    lblClass.showClassLabels = True
                    lyr.showLabels = True

labell(yourlayer, attributefield)
```